# Boundary at infinity for projective manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, projective-geometry

*Given a compact real projective manifold, is there something "like" a boundary at infinity for its universal cover?*

In the case of compact projective manifolds obtained from divisible convex sets (open convex sets admitting a co-compact action by a discrete group of projective transformations), the boundary of the convex set would be this "boundary at infinity". I would like to know whether such a thing exists (and how to define it) for universal covers of compact projective manifolds.

Comment: You are perhaps thinking of something like the Shafarevich conjecture: https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.0693

Comment: I forgot to say "real"!!

Comment: But that is interesting in any case. Thanks.